# What is the function of these transformers in an AM transmitter (Sender 5000 solid state AM transmitter)?

Tags: transformer, coil, amplitude-modulation

What could be the function of these transformers in the back of the Sender 5000 solid state AM transmitter?

[image: Transformer in an AM transmitter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a [modulation transformer](http://www.wa2fnq.com/4400/4400.htm) if that's what you thought. Modulation transformers were used in vacuum tube AM broadcast transmitters.

No, it's just a 3-phase line transformer with adjustable voltage taps to adapt to the actual line voltage.

Comment: aaahhh...i see. So it means that if the line voltage coming from electrical post is 110 V, we can set the 3-phase line transformer to produce 110 V too?

Comment: @ArcheanEon: No.  You adjust the transformer taps to match the input mains voltage, so the transformer outputs whatever the equipment requires.  This allows the equipment to be adjusted to operate from different mains supply voltages.